# how can i make resize to controls(Panel ,Grid) itself when window is maximize in .net

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

I create a small application in which, i want when my window(WPF) is maximized it's controls are also resized  according to window size.I tried this code-

```
 If Me.WindowState = Windows.WindowState.Maximized Then
        Me.WindowState = Windows.WindowState.Normal
        Me.Width = 820
        Me.Height = 440
        Me.Grid1.Width = 780
        Me.Grid1.Height = 400
        Me.StackPanel1.Height = 360
        Me.StackPanel1.Width = 140
        Me.StackPanel2.Height = 360
        Me.StackPanel2.Width = 600
 Else If Me.WindowState = Windows.WindowState.Normal Then
        Me.WindowState = Windows.WindowState.Maximized
        'Me.Width = 1350
        'Me.Height = 600
        Me.Grid1.Width = 1300
        Me.Grid1.Height = 600
        Me.StackPanel1.Height = 460
        Me.StackPanel1.Width = 200
        Me.StackPanel2.Height = 460
        Me.StackPanel2.Width = 800
```

Comment: In which event you wrote this code?

Comment: @Nisarg Button name is Maximize

'Private Sub Maximize_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Maximize.Click'

Comment: Try creating a Resorce Directory. That will act as StyleSheet for your application.

Answer (score 1):

Why you can't wrap your controls inside Grid? When you set columns width and rows height using *, it will change columns and rows size whenever window be resized. Also controls should have HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment set to Stretch.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it directly from XAML: using HorizontalAlignment/VerticalAlignment properies or with Binding to element's Width/Height in complex cases. Here is example from my project:

```
<GroupBox .... Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=TreeView, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=ActualWidth}">
```

Comment: hi, can you pls teach me how to use the exact same you wrote but divide the width by 2? or substract from it 100? thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should use a table-layout panel, and doc your controls inside!